# Intersection of a family of sets of positive Lebesgue measure has positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a family of subsets of the real numbers, denoted by $A_s$, where $s \in S \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $S$ has positive measure. If $A_s$ has positive Lebesgue measure for all $s \in S$, is it true that we can find $\rho \subset S$ such that $L = \cap_{t \in \rho} A_t$ has positive measure?

Edit: $\rho$ must have positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm)

Comment: $\rho=\{s\}$ for some $s\in S$

Comment: Since $S$ is only used as an index set, only the cardinality of $S$ is relevant, and so regarding $S$ you only need to say it has cardinality $c = 2^{\aleph_0}$ (no need to say $S \subset \mathbb R$ and no need to say $S$ has positive measure). That said, I'm still not sure you're phrased the question as intended. [This recent mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385017/15780) (and the comments, including my linked sci.math post) may be relevant to what you wanted to ask.

Comment: @saulspatz I forgot to mention that $\rho$ has to have positive measure, sorry!